# PHP Mail Not Returning True or False

Tags: php, html, email, post, return

I'm creating a contact us form, which should e-mail me the contents of the form. I tried to send mail on my localhost, and it didn't work, but it works perfectly when on a host (1and1). Now, I'm trying it out on a new host (Netfirms). FOr some apparent reason, the mail function doesn't send the mail, and it doesn't return a true/false value. I've tried googling a solution or a theory all night, but it was no use. What could be causing this weird result?

Here is the PHP for the mailing.

```
<?php
class zMail {

final public function compileMail() {
    global $tpl, $zip;

    $tpl->Define('error', null);

    # Ensure that the form was sent #
    if(isset($_POST['contact-us'])) { 

        # Make sure that the variables are set for the mailing process #
        $first_name     = $_POST['f_name'];
        $last_name      = $_POST['l_name'];
        $event_type     = $_POST['event'];
        $date           = $_POST['date'];
        $guests         = $_POST['guests'];
        $from           = $_POST['email'];
        $phone          = $_POST['phone'];

        # Place Where E-Mail should be sent to #
        $to             = $zip['Social']['Email'];

        # Are all fields completed? #
        if(!empty($first_name) && !empty($last_name) && !empty($event_type) && !empty($date) && !empty($guests) && !empty($from) && !empty($phone)) {
            switch($event_type) {
                case '1':
                    return 'Baby Shower';
                break;
                case '2':
                    return 'Wedding';
                break;
                case '3':
                    return 'Kids Party';
                break;
                case '4':
                    return 'Birthday';
                break;
                case '5':
                    return 'Other';
                break;
            }

            switch($guests) {
                case '1':
                    return '10-25 People';
                break;
                case '2':
                    return '25 - 50 People';
                break;
                case '3':
                    return '50 - 75 People';
                break;
                case '4':
                    return '75 - 100+ People';
                break;
            }

            $message = '<ul>
                            <li><b>First & Last Name: </b><span style="float: right;">' . $first_name . ' ' . $last_name . '</span></li>
                            <li><b>Event Type: </b><span style="float: right;">' . $event_type . '</span></li>
                            <li><b>Date: </b><span style="float: right;">' . $date . '</span></li>
                            <li><b>Guests: </b><span style="float: right;">' . $guests . '</span></li>
                            <li><b>Email: </b><span style="float: right;">' . $from . '</span></li>
                            <li><b>Telephone: </b><span style="float: right;">' . $phone . '</span></li>
                            <li><b>Add`l Information: </b><span style="float: right;">' . $notes . '</span></li>
                        </ul>';

            $subject = "{site: title} - New Client Inquiry";
            $headers = "From: IntactDev@gmail.com\r\n" . 
                        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n" . 
                        "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" . 
                        "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n" . 
                        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n\r\n"; 

            $retval = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
            if($retval == true) {
              $tpl->Define('error', '<span class="error">Message sent successfully!</span>');
            } else {
              $tpl->Define('error', '<span class="error">Email could not be sent!</span>');
           }
        } else {
            $tpl->Define('error', '<span class="error">Please fill in all fields!</span>');
        }
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: If it doesn't return `true` or `false`, what does it return instead?

Comment: what is the result of `var_dump($retval)`? also, if you are using error suppression in your application, you may want to var_dump(error_get_last()) as well, during testing.

Comment: It should return true or false. Are you saying this because you don't see either of the error messages defined below the `mail()` call?

Comment: @Barmar it returns no value at all.. just refreshes the page, but if you leave a field blank it will throw an error, as it should.

Comment: It's not possible. One or the other branch of the `if` will always be taken, unless there's an error signalled and a `try/catch` handler around the call. Absent that, I suspect something is overwriting the error span, or the page is redirecting.

Comment: Something's up @JacobS.. I tried to do vardump($retval) & it still returns nothing... I don't know why.

Comment: It almost looks to me like this code is never getting executed. The form is posting to itself? Where do you check to see if this is being submitted and call the `compileMail()` method?

Comment: @immulatin It is being submitted.. if you leave the "First Name" field empty it will throw an error above the form. Try it **bold** [here](http://demo.thepelicanville.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm curious how this ever worked on the other host. You are exiting out of the function before you ever get to the mail function.

Your two switch statements:

```
        switch($event_type) {
            case '1':
                return 'Baby Shower';
            break;
            case '2':
                return 'Wedding';
            break;
            case '3':
                return 'Kids Party';
            break;
            case '4':
                return 'Birthday';
            break;
            case '5':
                return 'Other';
            break;
        }

        switch($guests) {
            case '1':
                return '10-25 People';
            break;
            case '2':
                return '25 - 50 People';
            break;
            case '3':
                return '50 - 75 People';
            break;
            case '4':
                return '75 - 100+ People';
            break;
        }
```

These are returning strings, which means as long as a case was matched, NO code after the switch statements will ever get executed.

Maybe you are trying to redefine the variables like so:

```
switch($event_type) {
    case '1':
        $event_type =  'Baby Shower';
        break;
    case '2':
        $event_type =  'Wedding';
        break;
    case '3':
        $event_type =  'Kids Party';
        break;
    case '4':
        $event_type =  'Birthday';
        break;
    case '5':
        $event_type =  'Other';
        break;
}

switch($guests) {
    case '1':
        $guests =  '10-25 People';
        break;
    case '2':
        $guests =  '25 - 50 People';
        break;
    case '3':
        $guests =  '50 - 75 People';
        break;
    case '4':
        $guests =  '75 - 100+ People';
        break;
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear, can you accept this answer for future references?

Comment: I don't have enough rep. points to do that - but I would've if I could've.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if port 25 is open? Here is a link: 
http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

Comment: The port is open, so that can't be the problem.